# Query Not updating in Sqlite

Tags: ios, database, xcode, sqlite

Using For in loop inserting or updating table using SQlite query ,it's throw updating correctly message and also Error while updating. 'unknown error' error msg also.Insertion is done correctly but update not worked same if run update query in SQLite Manager it worked..thanks advance

```
sqlite3 *database;
NSString * databaseName=[[NSString alloc]initWithString:DBName];
NSArray * documentPaths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDir = [documentPaths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString * databasePath = [[documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:databaseName] retain];
NSString *lite;
BOOL check=[self isContainsID:filename];
if(check)
{
    lite=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"INSERT INTO table_name(id,filename,date)VALUES('%@',%d,'%@')",id,filename,date];
}
else
{
    lite=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"UPDATE table_name SET date='%@' where filename ='%@'",date,filename];
const char *sqlStatement = [lite UTF8String];

// Open the database from the users filessytem
if(sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
{
    // Setup the SQL Statement and compile it for faster access
    sqlite3_stmt *compiledStatement=nil;

    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, sqlStatement, -1, &compiledStatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        if(Debug)
        {
            DLog(@"not updated");
            DLog(@"HMM, COULDNT RUN QUERY: %s\n", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
        }
    }

    else
    {
        if (sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_DONE)
        {

                DLog(@"updated successfully");
        }
        if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(compiledStatement))
            NSLog(@"Error while updating. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));

    }
    sqlite3_finalize(compiledStatement);
}
sqlite3_close(database);
[databaseName release];
[databasePath release];
```

Comment: Sorry ,i am using UPDATE table_name SET date= only in programme..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is wrong and results in calling `sqlite3_step()` twice:

```
if (sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_DONE)
{
    DLog(@"updated successfully");
}
if(SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(compiledStatement))
   NSLog(@"Error while updating. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
```

I'm sure you meant:

```
if (sqlite3_step(compiledStatement) == SQLITE_DONE)
{
    DLog(@"updated successfully");
}
else
{
   NSLog(@"Error while updating. '%s'", sqlite3_errmsg(database));
}
```

Also you should be binding your statement variable instead of formatting them into the statement with `[NSString stringWithFormat:]`, as it's both more secure and allows the statements to be re-used (which is the point of preparing them).

Comment: but datas inserting correctly, when datas are updating then only not updating correctly.